# LZW TIFF to JPG conversion with Pillow - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tiff, python-imaging-library, lzw

I'm trying to create structured JPG preview for my TIFF database, but most of the files in collection are LZW compressed. I'm using this code to open TIFF file

```
import os
import sys
from PIL import Image

curdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
fname = 'TIFF - LZW - sample.tif'
#fname = 'TIFF - uncompressed - sample.tif'

jpg_size = 1200, 1200

tif = Image.open(os.path.join(curdir,fname))
tif.thumbnail(jpg_size)
tif.save(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(curdir, fname))[0] + '.jpg', 'JPEG', quality = 80)  

input('OK!')
```

with uncompressed sample it is totally OK, but with LZW TIFF code returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "APR - script - TIFF test.py", line 15, in <module>
    tif = Image.open(os.path.join(curdir,fname))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2286, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file 'D:\\SCRIPT\\TIFF\\TIFF - LZW - sample.tif'
```

I'm using Python 2.7 with Windows 7

What I have already done:

- installed win binaries of LIBTIFF from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm
- added C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin to PATH
- installed pylibtiff
- reinstalled PILLOW
- checked that 'import libtiff' works correctly

is it possible, that this kind of compression is still not supported? or how can I check that PILLOW found LIBTIFF library and it really works?

maybe there's another issue with TIFF file?

maybe any other advices no how can I convert LZW TIFF to JPG preview with Python?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24531139/TIFF%20-%20LZW%20-%20sample.tif - my tiff file